# how to position divs such that <p> tags won't disrupt the position?

Tags: css, html, web, positioning

i am having this problem with adjusting my div positions. i have separated many divs so they represent, header, menupane, rightpane, leftpane and footer. pls check out the code in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kj5pe/

the code is, html:

```
<div id="main">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <a href="#" class="buttons">Aaaa</a>
            <a href="#" class="buttons">Eeee</a>
            <a href="#" class="buttons">Iiii</a>
            <a href="#" class="buttons">Oooo</a>
            <a href="#" class="buttons">Uuuu</a>
        </div>
        <div id="leftpane">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
        <div id="rightpane">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
        <div id="midpane">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>Copyright &copy;</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#main
{
    width: 65em;
    height: 35em;
    margin: auto;
}

#header
{
    background-color: #ffb400;
    height: 5em;
}

#menu
{
    background-color: #ffe63e;
    height: 3em;
}

.buttons
{
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px #ffb400;
    color: #001e59;
    line-height: 3em;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    display: block;
    font-family: consolas ,Segoe UI, courier new;
}

.buttons:hover
{
    background-color: #ffb400;
}

#leftpane
{
    height:25em;
    width: 15em;
    float: left;
    background-color: #b8c3d9;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: -1px 1px #000000;
}

#rightpane
{
    height:25em;
    width: 15em;
    float: right;
    background-color: #b8c3d9;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: -1px 1px #000000;
}

#midpane
{
    background-color: #a1abbf;
    height: 25em;
    width: 35em;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: -1px 1px #000000;
}

#footer
{
    height: 1.8em;
    background-color: #ffb400;
    margin-top: -1em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: -1px 1px #000000;
}
```

please take note that the footer has margin-top: -1em... i had to do it. otherwise there is a gap between the footer and rest of the divs. why does this happen? it does not happen to the other divs, but why only the footer?

also, notice that the midpane also has a gap from the header. this is because i used

tags inside the midpane div. if i remove them, everything is back to normal. but why would i have to resort to that? why does this happen? i do the same thing in the left and right panes, but this does not happen. why is the middle pane the only one that is acting differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the p tag to have no margin/padding

```
p
{
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/MeDGa/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to interfere with the styling of the p tags (so you keep the formatting of your paragraphs). You can also set this:

```
#midpane {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kj5pe/9/)

by setting the div that is floating's display to inline block the margin/padding shouldn't effect the div.